Работа с API и параметры GET-запроса
ссылка на документацию API: https://textgears.com/ru/api#suggest
мой ключ для запрсов: WUfcuy1KqLvLu4xU
Работа с API, которая делает различную работу с текстом, в моем случае мне нужна автокоррекция текста.
Есть определенные параметры для работы с данным API
Я их пишу в параметры запроса
async function lol(){

    let response = await fetch("https://api.textgears.com/correct", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Basic WUfcuy1KqLvLu4xU",
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },

        text: 'Привет дружище',
        language: 'ru-RU',
     
    }) 
    let lol = await response.json()
    console.log(lol)
}

не получается, выдает пустое свойство corrected, хотя в нем должен был быть исправленный текст
Если написать эти параметры в body, то тоже не получается и выдается ошибка
async function lol(){

    let response = await fetch("https://api.textgears.com/correct", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Basic WUfcuy1KqLvLu4xU",
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },

        body: JSON.stringify({
               text: 'Привет дружище',
               language: 'ru-RU',
        })
     
    }) 
    let lol = await response.json()
    console.log(lol)
}


ВОПРОС!!! Что я делаю не так?

Напрямую, то есть через url, у меня получается все сделать.
let response = await fetch("https://api.textgears.com/correct?text=привет дружице..&language=ru-RU", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Basic WUfcuy1KqLvLu4xU",
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
    })

let lol = await response.json()
console.log(lol)


используйте тот код, где вы сформировали body, но напишите method: 'POST',. и почитайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/fetch, а то первый кусок кода говорит о том что вы недостаточно внимательно читали

Либо добавляйте текст в сам урл запроса(как раз get получается)

@SwaD лучше использовать post так как количество символов в тексте может выйти за ограничение размера query string

@nörbörnën да это понятно )

@nörbörnën, ну уж это к разработчикам апи, а не к автору. Впрочем, это может быть способом ограничить длину текста для ИИ (хотя, сомнительная идея). Тем более, по стандарту ограничения на длину url нет.

@Qwertiy по документации, post поддерживается

@nörbörnën, не вижу. Может где-то и написано, но искать не хочу...

в разделе «Авторизация и передача параметров»


text: 'Привет дружище',


16 стрелок хватит, чтобы стало заметно ответ на вашем же скриншоте в красной рамке с пометкой "Важно"?


UPDATE: А нет, вы ещё и параметры неправильно посылаете. Это GET-запрос, а у него тело в принципе не предусмотрено стандартом. Впрочем, пример запроса на этом скриншоте тоже имеется.

Огонь! С мобилы это видно не было :)

По поводу пометки ВАЖНО, все у них работает! А по поводу GET-запрос с его отсутствием тела, спасибо, не знал!

@djakuzi, даже если работает, когда вопрос задаёшь, надо валидные данные показывать, а не те, на которых, возможно, работает ;)
